# Adding logo to RefineryCMS nav

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, refinerycms

I just starting using Refinery and I am trying to add my clients logo in the navbar so it acts as the home page link but can't figure out how I could accomplish this. This is what I have so far:

application.html.erb

```
<header id="header">
   <%= render "/refinery/header" -%>
</header>
```

_header.html.erb

```
 <%= zurb_menu.to_html %>
```

application_helper.rb

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def zurb_menu
  menu_items = Refinery::Menu.new(Refinery::Page.fast_menu)

  presenter = Refinery::Pages::MenuPresenter.new(menu_items, self)
  presenter.css = "top-bar-section"
  presenter.dom_id = nil
  presenter.menu_tag = :section
  presenter.list_tag = "ul class='left'"
  presenter
 end
end
```

Comment: it would be good to get a few more details as to what is going on. Error messages? Blank screens? None of the code above seems to relate to logos at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding it to **Application Helper** and calling in your `_header.html.erb` is the actual way of implementing.

Instead if you wanted to do it without risk, you can directly include the logo by editing the `application.html.erb` and adding the

`<img style="" src="/system/images/Wsdsds/logo.png"/>`

before or after

`<%= render "/refinery/header" -%>`

as you wish and this will be shown to every page where the header id refers. Similarly you can overwrite any view files.

In case, if the `_header.html.erb` is invisible you can easily make it visible by using the refinery override,

```
$ rake refinery:override view=refinery/*
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically you'd put a logo helper in your Application helper

```
def logo
    image_tag("some_graphic.png",
      :alt => ::Refinery::Setting.find_or_set(:site_name, "Project Name"))
end
```

and call it in your _header.html.erb partial

```
<div id='logo'>
  <%= link_to logo, refinery.root_path%>
</div>
```